# Gnuplot: how to mimic sketch graphs

Tags: gnuplot, sketching

I want to plot a figure like this one:

[image]

but with only sketched data curves. The x and y axes should not be sketched.

Is this possible using Gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may find this link useful, since it's exactly what you are asking for :)

http://rfonseca.github.io/xkcd-gnuplot/

Essentially, it applies a function to *jiggle* the line and make it pseudo-hand-drawn:

```
jiggle(x) = x*(1+(2*rand(0)-0.5)*0.015)
plot jiggle(sin(x))
```

And this is the result:

[image]

You may also want to increase samples with `set samples 1000` to have better results avoiding spikes in *jiggled* lines.

(As a curiosity, that page is inspired by [a StackExchange answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs), that contains a very advanced (and amazing, IMHO) approach to this problem, unfortunately only for Mathematica users.)